# How make automatic calculate

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

How to calculate using jquery or Javascript in Codeigniter as below requirement 
I have 3 input element to calculate after user complete they form element :

```
1, Quantity
2, Unitprice
3, Total.
```

**By Total = quantity * unitprice.**

```
<td><?php echo form_input('quantity','',' class="form-control"')?></td>
<td><?php echo form_input('unitprice','',' class="unit form-control" placeholder="unit pricee"')?></td>
<td><?php echo form_label('','total','class="form_control"')?></td>
```

[image]

I try to write javascript like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.unitprice').keyup(function () {
         Calculate();
         });
    });

function Calculate() { 
             var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity").val();
             var unitprice = document.getElementsByClassName("unitprice").val();
             var total = quantity * unitprice;
              $('.total').val(total);
              } 
    </script>
```

But it is not work

Thanks advance!!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I can help you with problems, but not with writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(function(){
$('.qty, .unit').on('blur', function(e){
  var qty = parseFloat( $('.qty').val() ), 
      unit = parseFloat( $('.unit').val() );

  if( isNaN(qty) || isNaN(unit) ) {
    $('.result').text('');
    return false;
  }

  var total = qty * unit;
  $('.result').text( total );
});
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ceropivola/1/watch?html,js,output)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much. How to validate for number only?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example, since I was bored. Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sgnl/44ts8ucf/1/

html

```
<input type="text" id="quantity" class="calc_element"> Quantity
<input type="text" id="unit_price" class="calc_element"> Unit Price
<div id="total"></div>
```

javascript

```
// get some IDs or classes on your elements to target them easily
var total = $('#total');

// bind an event that triggers on KEYUP
$('.calc_element').on('keyup', function(){
  // when triggered get the values from the input elements
  // via jQuery's '.val()' method
  var quantity = $('#quantity').val() || 1;
  var unit_price = $('#unit_price').val();

  var result = (quantity * unit_price) + " total";

  // set the innerHTML of the div to your calculated total
  total.html(result);
});
```

YMMV, thats the jist of it, some tweaking will need to be down for your code.

Comment: you would have to add validation code perhaps as a function which checks the value of what .val() returns.